# JQuery Mobile remove text to dynamically generated back buttons

Tags: jquery-mobile, back-button

I'd like to remove the text from the dynamically generated back buttons (e.g., nested lists) to achieve something like this static header (**ONLY** the arrow is displayed):

```
<header data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <a data-rel="back" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
</header>
```

Since this solution is not working properly,

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText = "";
}
```

I've tried this one, but it's not working:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforecreate', function(){ 
    $("a:jqmData(rel='back')").jqmData("iconpos", "notext");
});
```

Where is the mistake?

**EDIT**
To make the question easier, I'd like to remove the text of the button in the nested list, example: http://jsfiddle.net/GV2wN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clean since it modifies the button's css after it is rendered, but adding this seems to do the trick:

```
$(document).on('pagechange', function () {
    $.mobile.activePage.find(".ui-header a.ui-btn-left").addClass("ui-btn-icon-notext");
    $.mobile.activePage.find(".ui-header a.ui-btn-left").removeClass("ui-btn-icon-left");
});​
```

[Here's your updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/GV2wN/5/)

There is sometimes a delay between the button being rendered and its markup being changed, so you may want to look for a better event to bind to, maybe a click event?

Comment: Hmmm good workaround! Maybe next JQuery Mobile releases will address this problem

Comment: An issue was added two years ago, but so far it seems no change has been made : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1744

Comment: Late reply here however so those looking to implement this solution I found changing the event trigger to pagebeforeshow removed the back button text without any rendering issues as it happens prior to displaying the page

Answer (score 1):

> If you'd like to configure the back button text, you can either use
>   the data-back-btn-text="previous" attribute on your page element, or
>   set it programmatically via the page plugin's options.
>
> Source: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

```
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.backBtnText = "Previous";
```

(Replace "previous" with whatever text you would like displayed.

Alternatively, you can do this on a page-by-page basis adding the `data-back-btn-text="Previous"` on your `data-role="page"` div as seen here:

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Previous">
```

**UPDATE (1)**

Sorry I missed you had already tried the above method.

**Solution:** By inserting `data-iconpos="notext"` on a `data-role="button"` link, it will produce the icon without the button text, as shown below:

```
<a href="index.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext">Back</a>
```

Here's a working jsFiddle example, putting the button in the Header element: http://jsfiddle.net/3q28f/

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have answered with a solution that I have already mentioned as a not working one. I'd like to remove the whole text and to have only the arrow in the header (like my first sentence said).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you had already tried that. I updated my answer, and included a working example.

Comment: You have not get the question...it is better to explain with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/GV2wN/

Comment: Thanks adamdehaven ! It helped me to remove the Button text. +1 for this !